# Hibernate TemporalType.TIMESTAMP авто обновление

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, java-ee

Как через гибернейт создать поле в бд (postgresql), которое будет автоматически проставлять дату при создании нового кортежа? 
Сейчас у меня так:

```
@Column(name = "date", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date;
```

Но это не работает, значение в столбце не появляется. 
Использую `hbm.auto = update`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/221827/5694145

Answer (score 2):

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date registrationDate;

public User() {
    this.registrationDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
}
```